# Lenovo A859 touchscreen touches itself

Tags: touchscreen, lenovo

For about 2 weeks my phone's touchscreen is acting weird.

It looks like it touches itself in the upper left corner of the screen. I didn't find any pattern, it does this randomly for a random amount of time, only when the screen is unlocked.

I did a factory reset already and I installed Avast to scan it and nothing came up.

Is it a software or a hardware problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a hardware problem and you may need a new screen. Yours may be damaged.

It might also be a battery pack that has expanded from frequent heavy usage. This can push against the screen from the inside resulting in a similar effect sometimes.

It's also possible it's a result of being flexed in a certain way such that there is extra strain on the corner. I'm speculating that the corners are often used to hold the weight of the device.